# How do I read an exe file into ram then launch it from Python?

Tags: python, encryption

My goal is to encrypt my exe file for distribution and store it in a python decrypting launcher.  When the python launcher starts, it will use a key to decrypt the app and write the exe to ram. I then want python to launch the exe from ram.

I have the exe created, but I am unsure how to use python to read this file into ram then launch the decrypted exe string. Is this possible?

Comment: Does the python launcher contain the encryption secret?

Comment: Security is *hard*.

The proposed security you are considering is not effective. Someone can read the encryption secret from your launcher. 

There are ways to get around this, but they basically require phone-home DRM and massive rootkit-like functionality.

In short, to get what you want, you'd have to do many things most programmers consider evil - often with good reason. 

So, don't do this.

Comment: I would store the key in the launcher, yes. I'm not set up for phone home solutions, nor would I expect the customer to boot with amnesia for their own safety of their work. So, I'm just looking for a middle ground, to make things difficult not perfect.

Comment: The point is that if the decryption secret is stored in the launcher, *especially a python one*, then there's basically no point in having the secret because anyone that has the launcher has the secret, and presumably anyone that has access to the binary also has access to the launcher. And once that secret is exposed once, your encryption has become useless.

Answer (score 0):

have you ever tried using subprocess:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(["bash", "file.sh"])
```

and the in the file.sh:

```
mcs urpgm.exe
mono urpgm.exe
```

for me it does not work but for some people it does